# if $x^2=y^3$, then $x=a^3$ and $y=b^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We are given that $x^2 = y^3$ and that $x,y$ are positive integers.

We need to show that there are $a,b$ positive integers such that

$x=a^3$, and $y=b^2$.

I tried to do modular arithmetic in order to solve this problem but I got nowhere. I can't see how one would proceed for this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Think of the prime decompositions of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Not true for $x=8,y=4$.

Comment: @Oldboy wrote it down wrong, good catch, thanks!

Comment: The title is still incorrect

Comment: If the claim is true, then $a=b$, you don't need two numbers.

Comment: if $x= p_1 ^{i_1} \dots p_n^{i_n}$ and $y= p_1 ^{j_1} \dots p_n^{j_n}$, then we obtain $2i_k =3j_k$ and the only integer solutions are $i_k =3t_k$ for some integers $t_k$ and $j_k =2 s_k$ for integers $s_k$. Is this the correct argument?

Comment: @SeanThrasher: yes, this argument is correct (because the prime decomposition is unique and because $2,3$ are relative primes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x^2=y^3$, $y^3$ is a perfect square. Hence all its prime factors have an even multiplicity. At the same time, these multiplicities are multiple of $3$, hence they are multiple of $6$. Both $x^2$ and $y^3$ are perfect sixth powers, from which the claim follows.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is correct, then:

$$
\begin{align}
x^2 &= y^3 \\
\left(a^3\right)^2 &= \left(b^3\right)^2 \\
a^6 &= b^6 \\
a &= \pm b
\end{align}
$$

Because $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a = b$.

So in conclusion: $x^2 = y^3$ if and only if $a = b$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is not the question asked !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Well, I am realy not seeing what I missed out. Although you had the same answer in a comment...

Comment: My comment was *not* an answer, this is precisely why it is a comment. Re-read the question, it is not ambiguous.